# Naming an action Get... makes it a HttpGet, in spite of HttpPostAttribute. How do I force it to be HttpPost?

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, get

I have the code below in my controller, based on ApiController. (Inserted in a VS2013 MVC templated project).

If I name the action GetUniquePoSId, I can't invoke it using POST. Changing the name to FetchUniquePoSId makes it possible.

I should like to select my action names freely; anyone who knows how to disable this behaviour?

Thanks,
Anders, Denmark

```js
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage FetchUniquePoSId([FromBody]JToken token)
        {
            var validationMessage = _jsonValidator.Validate(token, new string[] { "MerchantId" });

            if (validationMessage.ValidationResult != ValidationResultEnum.Ok)
                return MpBadRequest(validationMessage);

            // Otherwise OK.
            return Request.CreateResponse<JToken>(JToken.Parse("{'MobilePayPosId': 'A1234567-3AEA-4069-A2DD-123456789012'}"));
        }
```

Comment: I'm absolutely sure the naming here isn't the problem. You can name your `Actions` whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an `HttpPost` attribute from `System.Web.Mvc` namespace in a web api project, that's why it's not working for you (System.Web.Mvc namespace should only be consumed by asp.net mvc controllers).

You should be using `System.Web.Http` namespace which is used for web api projects.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage FetchUniquePoSId([FromBody]JToken token)
{
    //handling request
}
```